# How to enhance the views in one Django app with code in a different app

Tags: django-templates, django-views

I am working on my first Django website and I've factored independent parts of the website into different apps. There is one fundamental app (I'll call it MainApp for the purposes of this question) on which other apps depend (I'll call the dependent apps AppX, AppY, and AppZ). The MainApp provides some views that I'd like dependent apps to contribute to, but I'm not sure how to do that without making MainApp dependent on AppX, AppY, and AppZ.

Let's say that MainApp has a view at URL /MainApp/TheView/. Does Django provide any mechanism that could be used as "hooks" such that App[XYZ] could inject additional content into /MainApp/TheView/? I.e. is there a way to create MainApp views such that they can easily be extended by other arbitrary apps?

Comment: Okay, I believe I could understand what your question is. 

The only way I see is, Once the MainApp has completed whatever it could do, then you can redirect to a url from AppX or AppY, but doing so will change the clients view. 

If you don't want that to happen but maybe want to separate the functionality of your code then you may have to write a separate function in another file. 

Or the best, you could put the functionality of the AppX as a cron job, like using Celery.

Ultimately, there is no reason why you would create different apps unless, every app has its own urls and views mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

First I added an **extra_content_providers** attribute to the view class in MainApp. It will contain references to extra content providers. The get method fetches the extra content and passes it along to the template.

```
class SpamView(View):
    extra_content_providers = []
    def get(self, request, ...):
        ...
        extra_content = ""
        for provider in self.extra_content_providers:
            extra_content += provider(...)
        params = {..., 'extra_content': extra_content}
        return render(request, 'example.html', params)
```

Then I defined a decorator next to the view class:

```
def spamview_content_provider(f):
    SpamView.extra_content_providers.append(f)
    return f
```

Finally, AppX defined its contribution this way:

```
from MainApp.views import spamview_content_provider

@spamview_content_provider
def x_content(...):
    return "Hello, I'm X."
```

This is a plain-old Python solution and it lets App[XYZ] provide extra content to MainApp views without introducing any new inter-app dependencies.